# What is !! in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript and came along this line while reverse engineering some code

```
if (msrc.readyState != 'open' && !!msrc.progressTimer)

var useArg = !!/youtube.com/.exec(url)
```

[these are not consecutive lines in code]

Can anybody tell what is !! ?
Is it some kind of operator or what ?

I tried googling but could not find anything helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: asked many times before.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: I remember the first time I encountered truthy and falsey.  It's fun!